# when inviting facebook friends to an app, is there a way to avoid confirmation dialog box?

Tags: facebook

I'm currently using the below code to send an invitation to a user's facebook friends. However once the function is run, a confirmation dialog box pops up and I have to confirm that I would like to send the requests to my friends. I'd like to skip this extra step. Is there a way to avoid this confirmation dialog box?

```
FB.ui({method:'apprequests', message:'would like you to try out our app!', to: ids});
```

Comment: Just imagine how this could be abused... Thankfully there is no way to bypass this. Facebook wants to make sure that there is actually a willing user on the other side of the screen and not just some spam bot sending out app invites...

Comment: @Lix that's really unfortunate. What I've created is essentially the multi friend selector dialog box except that instead of a popup, it shows up on the website. I wanted to skip the step of clicking a link to have it pop up and instead created a widget on my home page that mimics the multi friend selector. Now, the user will still see a popup. Oh well.

Comment: I'm sure your intentions were good ones. However I think you can appreciate the dangers that such a bypass would create...

Comment: how does candy crush sends invitations without user confirmation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No!!!!!!!

Facebook do not want apps sending invitations without the user's permission. This would be evil spam.